# Is there a fast way to scrape player stats on Futbin with BS4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For a personal I'm working on a webscraping project to scrape player stats on futbin.com.
I noticed that the stats on the website are not in table tags but in div tags and was wondering if there is a fast way to scrape all those stats in one time instead of line by line.

[Example](https://www.futbin.com/21/player/541/lionel-messi)

I already scraped the information on the left side of the screen with this function:

```
def myhtml(url):
    # use BS4 to get table that has required data
    html = str(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser').find('div', id='info_content').find("table"))
    # read_html() returns a list, take first one,  first column are attribute name, transpose to build DF
    return pd.read_html(html)[0].set_index(0).T
```

Now I'm looking to scrape all the individual stats. In my code below I only scrape the
"key" stats that are available on the card.
Function for the stats I had so far:

```
def stats_scraper(url):
    # Empty lists to save stats in 
    # Pace
    pace_list = []
    shooting_list = []
    passing_list = []
    dribbling_list = []
    defending_list = []
    physical_list = []
    # Looping through all the links
    for link in url:
        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        # Find the player stats
        pace = soup.find_all('div', id='main-pace-val-0')
        shooting = soup.find_all('div', id='main-shooting-val-0')
        passing = soup.find_all('div', id='main-passing-val-0') 
        dribbling = soup.find_all('div', id='main-dribblingp-val-0') 
        defending = soup.find_all('div', id='main-defending-val-0') 
        physical = soup.find_all('div', id='main-heading-val-0')
        # Looping through every stat
        for stat in pace:
            try:
              pace_list.append(stat.text.strip())
            except AttributeError:
              pace_list.append(np.nan)

        for stat in shooting:
            try:
              shooting_list.append(stat.text.strip())
            except AttributeError:
              shooting_list.append(np.nan)

        for stat in passing:
            try:
              passing_list.append(stat.text.strip())
            except AttributeError:
              passing_list.append(np.nan)

        for stat in dribbling:
            try:
              dribbling_list.append(stat.text.strip())
            except AttributeError:
              dribbling_list.append(np.nan)
        
        for stat in defending:
            try:
              defending_list.append(stat.text.strip())
            except AttributeError:
              defending_list.append(np.nan)

        for stat in physical:
            try:
              physical_list.append(stat.text.strip())
            except AttributeError:
              physical_list.append(np.nan)
        
    stats_frame = pd.DataFrame({
      'pace':pace_list,
      'shooting':shooting_list,
      'passing':passing_list,
      'dribbling':dribbling_list,
      'defending':defending_list,
      'physical':physical_list
    })
    return stats_frame
```

I was wondering if there was a fast way to scrape all the stats with less code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find_next()` to get values of various footballer's stats:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.futbin.com/21/player/541/lionel-messi"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = {}
for s in soup.select(".left_stat_name"):
    data[s.get_text(strip=True)] = s.find_next(class_="stat_val").get_text(
        strip=True
    )

print(pd.DataFrame([data]).T)
```

Prints:

```
                   0
Pace              85
Acceleration      91
Sprint Speed      80
Shooting          92
Positioning       93
Finishing         95
Shot Power        86
Long Shots        94
Volleys           88
Penalties         75
Passing           91
Vision            95
Crossing          85
FK. Accuracy      94
Short Passing     91
Long Passing      91
Curve             93
Dribbling         96
Agility           91
Balance           95
Reactions         94
Ball Control      96
Composure         96
Defending         38
Interceptions     40
Heading Accuracy  70
Def. Awareness    32
Standing Tackle   35
Sliding Tackle    24
Physicality       65
Jumping           68
Stamina           72
Strength          69
Aggression        44
```